# access choices from formal argument of function

Tags: r, arguments, optional-arguments

Is there a way to access the choices of an argument of a function?

In this silly example:

```
noise <- function(animal = c("dog","cat","chicken","pig")){ # default animal is "dog"
  animal <- match.arg(animal)
  sound <- c("woof","meow","cluck","oink")[match(animal, c("dog","cat","chicken","pig"))]
  sound
}
noise("chicken") # returns desired result
```

I would like to avoid retyping `c("dog","cat","chicken","pig")` by accessing the vector of choices from the declaration, something similar to (making this up):

```
noise <- function(animal = c("dog","cat","chicken","pig")){ 
      animal <- match.arg(animal)
      sound <- c("woof","meow","cluck","oink")[match(animal, self.choices("animal"))]
      sound
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this: `eval(formals(noise)[["animal"]])`

Comment: That's awesome, thanks -- this is possible because it's getting evaluated at run-time?  Because when defining the function `noise`, the function `noise` hasn't been defined yet...

Comment: I think it's a lucky outcome of lazy evaluation: R first parses the script, and by the time it's evaluating the body it already knows the function's signature

Comment: BTW there's probably a name-agnostic way to get this info within the function, but I never remember which of `sys.frame()` and its siblings is relevant.

Comment: I guess `eval(formals()[["animal"]])` called inside `noise` would suffice?